# Dom4j detach children without looping

Tags: java, dom4j

I'm trying to keep the attributes of a particular element without keeping any of the children.  There may be dozens of child elements under this one that I want to remove, and right now, I'm looping through them and detaching them one by one, which can hurt performance when there are a ton of children to remove.  I looked into cloning the element and detaching the old one, but the documentation says that this is a deep clone; same for the createCopy method.  Is there a more efficient way to do this than looping through the children one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could manually "shallow clone" the node -- create a new element node using the name/namespace from the existing one -- then move the attributes over and replace the old node with the new one.